# Hosting Nextra (Next.js static site generator) website on GitHub Pages

Tags: next.js, github-pages, static-site-generation

Some days ago I came across [Nextra](https://nextra.vercel.app/), which is a static site generator based on [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).

The docs explain how to deploy a site to [Vercel](https://nextra.vercel.app/get-started#quick-start-with-vercel) and I am wondering if I can deploy the site to [GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages) or any other platform that host static HTML sites.

From my understanding `yarn build` will **create a folder that includes html, css and js files** which can be **uploaded to GitHub pages**. Am I on the right track? Respectively **can Nextra pages be hosted on GitHub Pages**?

I cannot find a `build` folder that includes the generated website or something similar.

Thanks for every advice in advance.

Comment: You need to run `next export` to export your app to [static HTML](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export).

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I get Error: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`. But seems to be the right direction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To generate static files with no need of a Node.js server for hosting you can export your next app after build.

In `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "export": "next build && next export"
  }
```

Then `yarn export` and you will get the files in the `out/` folder.

With basic Nextra config you will get an error about image optimization:

> Error: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.

To avoid that error you should deactivate Next.js image optimization by providing the `images.unoptimized` option **outside** `require("nextra")({})`.

Like this:

```js
// next.config.js

const withNextra = require("nextra")({
  theme: "nextra-theme-docs",
  themeConfig: "./theme.config.tsx",
});

module.exports = {
  ...withNextra(),
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
};
```

[Here is a working example being deployed to Github Pages](https://github.com/mkrtchian/reading-notes).